# Error while closing file descriptors in bash with exec

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

I'm trying to make a script to test a program but I need to use some black magic with file descriptor and redirections.
But the problem is that I'm trying to use **exec file_descriptor > &-** to close it but the script is throwing an error here is the code and the errors:

```
for fd in "${fds[@]}"; do
    echo "Closing fd $fd and remove pipes"
    exec $fd<&-
    rm -f pipe$fd
done
```

and the fd's are created/stored like that:

```
pfd=25 #I start the file descriptors to 25 because my program open some file descriptors
fds=()
mkfifo pipe$pfd
exec $pfd>pipe$pfd
fds+=$pfd
pfd=$((( $pfd + 1 )))
```

And the error is

```
exec: 25: not found
```

I don't know why but exec don't want to be executed with the variable, when i remove the variable and put the number, it works. But I need to put the variable so I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: `pdf=25` and then `exec $pfd>...anything...` is bad form, btw. Better to let the shell auto-allocate the descriptor instead of setting a hardcoded number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
exec {fd}<&-
```

Note that this requires bash 4.1 or later; earlier versions could not substitute file descriptor numbers without using `eval`.

---

That said, consider letting bash auto-allocate all the descriptor numbers, and splitting them off from your pipe numbers.

```
pipe_names=( )
pipe_fds=( )
pipe_num=0

newpipe() {
  local pfd_new pipe_name="pipe${pipe_num}"
  mkfifo "$pipe_name" || return
  exec {pfd_new}>"$pipe_name" || return
  pipe_fds[$pipe_num]=$pfd_new
  pipe_names[$pipe_num]=$pipe_name
  (( ++pipe_num ))
}
```

Comment: See edit showing how to use auto allocation for the assignment so you don't need to worry about whether something is already using a FD number above 25.